# Spring Boot Configuration + RepositoryRestResource + Authentication

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to create a Spring Boot application which stores user/password combination in a users document with MongoDB.  I was able to successfully set up a repository extending MongoRepository and all works fine.  Now, I would like to set up authentication based on the data source my repository is connecting to.  Is there a quick way to do this just using the default connection, or do I need to specifically define a DataSource to do this?

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);
}
```

Here we should assume a dataSource is defined, but if I already have a REST repository set up, I don't have that yet.   Do I need an intermediary step here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in this case `UserDetailsService` interface will be your best friend

You have to implement the `UserDetailsService` interface and make sure that your Mongo DB Repository is injected into the `UserDetailsService` implementation that you create.  After that let's implement the `loadUserByUsername` method in order to return a `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` object and fill it with the Mongo DB user information.

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
@Service
public class MyUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    MyMongoRepo myMongoRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> dummyAuthorityForExample = Arrays.asList(new  SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        MyMongoUser mongoUser= myMongoRepo.findByUsername(s);
        User user = new User(mongoUser.getUsername(), mongoUser.getPassword(),dummyAuthorityForExample);
        return user;
    }
}
```

And finally inject the `UserDetailsService` to your `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`

```
@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
```

Comment: So I actually need to set a userDetailsService and not a jdbcAuthentication on my AuthenticationManagerBuilder?

Comment: yes it is becaus jdbc authentication will try to ger user data using sql querys but mongo database is a document based and nosql

Comment: actually you can prove this looking at the source code of JdbcUserDetailsManager thas is the UserDetailService implemented for jdbc authentication and you can see how the querys are created only as sql

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!